# How to make a text right below an icon in BottomAppBar in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So I have a BottomAppBar and i'm trying to have a text right below the icon button, I have tried using Column with mainaxissize set to min and I have also tried to use wrap with the lowest spacing i can do but none of these methods put the text right below the icon, there seems to be some type of gap or padding between the icon and the text that I would like to remove, how can i make the text right below the Icon?

here is the code:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    notchMargin: 4.0,
    child: new Row(
      // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        Wrap(
          direction: Axis.vertical,
            children: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home_outlined,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              onPressed: () => screenIndex(0)),
          Text("Home")
        ]),
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.history,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            onPressed: () => screenIndex(1)),
        SizedBox(width: 10),
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.message,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            onPressed: () => screenIndex(3)),
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.person_outline,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            onPressed: () => screenIndex(4)),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

This is what it is currently showing:

[image]

and I would like to have the text right underneath the icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the IconButton widget as follows

```
 Wrap(
              crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                direction: Axis.vertical,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.home_outlined,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                      onPressed: () => screenIndex(0)),
                  Text("Home")
                ]),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The iconbutton has a default padding. You cab use an icon and wrap it with inkwell or gesture detector like shown below

```
InkWell(
onTap: () => screenIndex(0),
Column(
 mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children:[
     Icon(Icons.home_outlined, color: Colors.grey),
     Text("Home")
  ]
 )
)
```

Comment: ok i didnt know about that padding thing, I think i'll keep using the same but I added padding and constraints set to zero

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked great for me, but this ended up being my solution, for a nice, round, clickable BottomAppBar button with the text beneath the icon - just put it in the `Row` `children`

```
SizedBox.fromSize(
    size: Size(56, 56),
    child: ClipOval(
      child: Material(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          child: InkWell(
              splashColor:
                  Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
              onTap: () {},
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.home),
                  Text(
                    "Home",
                    style: iconLabelStyle,
                  )
                ],
              ))),
    )),
```

For completenes, here's the style I'm using on the icon text:

```
var iconLabelStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelSmall?.copyWith(
      color: Colors.white,
    );
```